# How to make a Simulink model constant?

Tags: constants, simulink

I have a model in Simulink (2018a) which has more models inside. So I have:

```
parent.slx --> child.slx
```

I want `child.slx` to execute only once in the whole simulation, so basically its output will be constant at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [Model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model.html) Block to call the *child* model.  Put this block into an [Enabled Subsystem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/enabled-subsystems.html) Block in the *parent* model and create the enable signal in the following way:

[image]

You also need to make sure that the outport blocks within the subsystem are set to `hold` their value when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the entire contents of child.slx within a triggered subsystem in parent.slx.
If it absolutely must be a separate file then try calling it from a Matlab User-Defined block; you may need to use eml.extrinsic sim ... I doubt that'd work though.