# Simulink How to output a constant value

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a model in which I want to output a constant of the year when the capacity of the battery reaches 80% of its nominal capacity.

This is the model.
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymcJH.png)

The output of these two agings is like this:[Output of the agings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppw4F.png)

I was trying to use the method in [How to make a Simulink model constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869755/how-to-make-a-simulink-model-constant), but since my model is discrete, there is no year with an accurate output 0.2, so the "Compare To Constant Zero" block always outputs zero.

And when I changed the == into >=, it continuously outputs 1 after a certain year.

What I want is to output that certain year, for instance, in the year 2009 the first time the capacity of the battery reaches 80%, so output a constant 2009 forever.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this adding an edge detector: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/detectrisepositive.html

If you input your signal which changes to 1 in 2009, the edge detector will be 1 in 2009 and 0 otherwise.